# Asp.Net code block - how to use with a property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've used code blocks before, but I'm having an issue in this instance.

I have a user control with a small number of properties. I don't want to set the properties in the parent control so I've resorted to doing it like this:

```
     <uc2:ContactCard ID="ContactCard" runat="server"
        Address="<% =CoAddressStack %>"
        Email="<% =ContactEmail %>" />
```

The problem is that the properties are not being set with the value, instead they are set with the exact text inside the quotes.

The properties themselves come from an inherited base control.

I've been scratching my head for some time and seemingly tried every permutation. It could be I'm doing something wrong elsewhere - any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, it seems it's not possible to embed a code block into a controls property directly without resorting to other measures. This for me makes the idea redundant as it's just as  easy to set the controls properties from the code behind as it is to perform the extra measures.

Answer (score 0):

The tag you're looking for is `<%= ... %>` not `<% = ... %>`

There is not a space before the `=`

Comment: I've tried that too - I guess the problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this

```
Address="<%= 5 + 5 %>"
```

if it display 10, then its your property, in that case you can call a function like this

```
Address="<%= getValue() %>"
```

and in your codebehind something like

```
public string getValue()
{
   return "hello world";
}
```

also try deleting the quotes: `Address=<%= CoAddressStack %>`